# PowerShell command for new-item fails unexpectedly

Tags: powershell

Can anyone see why this methods to create a directory works several times in the script but, the last time I call it fails and I see no output?  No errors and not seeing the `Dir $path` result either.

The result is my git clone fails.

```
    _create_folder -path $destinationPath

    "$NL Downloading clone of repository ...." 
    git clone $repoAddress $destinationPath
    Dir $destinationPath

    "$NL Trying a repository pull ...." 
    git pull $repoAddress 

....

function _create_folder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path = ""
    )
    Begin {}
    Process
    {
        "$NL Creating $path ....."
        if(!(Test-Path -Path $path)) { 
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path -Verbose:$true
        }
        Dir $path
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function should be placed before the line where it is called. Is your script structured like the example in your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Function Not Recognised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351096/powershell-function-not-recognised)

Comment: The script is broken into several routines and I tried rearranging the main and helper functions.  Now wondering if `git clone` is doing something with the destination folder if failing.